# Rails to_param using non-id field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permalinks

Instead of using a row's `id` field to generate slugs (like this):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    [id, name.parameterize].join("-")
  end
end
```

I want to be able to use a non-id field, like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    [application_id, name.parameterize].join("-")
  end
end
```

It's still an integer, but instead of doing a find based on the `id`, it should do a find based on `application_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine, but you'll have to amend your find code to use the application_id.

```
@people = People.find_by_application_id(params[:id])
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Correct. Best to use the bang version, `find_by_application_id!`, though, so that it raises a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` like the original `find` method.